# W: Target Packages is configured multiple times

Tags: package-management

When I type `sudo apt-get update` I get the following message in the terminal

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Each warning message occurs when the package manager discovers a duplicate source.

To fix the problem, simply edit the source file and delete-or-disable one of the sources.

Let's deconstruct one sample line:

```
Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

Now let's look at it again:

```
Target Packages (PATH) is configured multiple times in FILE_1:LINE_1 and FILE_2:LINE_2
```

In order to fix the source for PATH (main/binary-amd64/Packages, Google Chrome):

- You can delete `FILE_1:LINE_1` (`/etc/apt/sources.list`, Line #52)
- Or you can delete `FILE_2:LINE_2` (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, Line #3)

**WARNING**: DO NOT DELETE all of `FILE_1` or `FILE_2`. Your system needs those files. Those are the files that tell your system where to get software upgrades from. NEVER DELETE the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` - it provides security upgrades.